# select rows having condition met for group (without temporary table)

Tags: sql-server, group-by

Having the table with 3 columns:

```
ID  category    flag
1       A       1
2       A       0
3       A       0
4       B       0
5       C       0
```

I want to select all rows that have `flag = 1` at least once per category.

Expected results:

```
ID  category    flag
1       A       1
2       A       0
3       A       0
```

It can be solved using a temporary table like this:

```
select ID into #tempTable from someTable where flag = 1
select * from someTable join #tempTable on someTable.ID = #tempTable.ID
```

But I'd prefer a solution with grouping, which I struggle to came up with. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`GROUP BY` cannot be used alone because it only returns 1 row per group (`category`).

---

- You can use a sub query with `flag = 1` and `INNER JOIN`:

  ```
  SELECT d1.ID, d1.category, d1.flag
  FROM data d1
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT category FROM data WHERE flag = 1
  ) d2 
      ON d2.category = d1.category ;
  ```
- You can use the `EXISTS` clause:

  ```
  SELECT d.ID, d.category, d.flag
  FROM data d
  WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM data WHERE flag = 1 AND category = d.category
  ) ;
  ```
- You can use `IN` clause (although `EXISTS` is better):

  ```
  SELECT d.ID, d.category, d.flag
  FROM data d
  WHERE d.category IN (SELECT category FROM data WHERE flag = 1) ;
  ```
- You can also use `CROSS APPLY` with a sub query on `flag = 1`:

  ```
  SELECT d.ID, d.category, d.flag
  FROM data d
  CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT TOP (1) category 
      FROM data 
      WHERE flag = 1 AND category = d.category
  ) ca ;
  ```

`DISTINCT` aren't needed if, for each category, only 1 row can have `flag = 1`.

#### Output:

```
ID  category    flag
1       A       1
2       A       0
3       A       0
```

Comment: DISTINCT is unnecessary for the IN predicate. And if only one row per category can have the flag of 1, DISTINCT is unnecessary at all.

Comment: @AndriyM correct about the `IN` query. But the OP has "*I want to select all rows that have flag = 1 **at least once** per category*" which makes me think that the `DISTINCT` is necessary in the other queries.

Comment: And in the `CROSS APPLY`, the `SELECT DISTINCT category` should probably be more efficient if replaced with `SELECT TOP (1) whatever`. It would effectively be another way to write an `EXISTS` subquery.

Comment: @Andriy This is why I added a note yesterday based on your initial comment: not needed if there is only 1 row with flag = 1.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `Flag` is a `BIT` column or an `INT` that takes only `0` and `1` as values, this could be achieved using windowed functions as well. For instance:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
  ID INT
  , Category VARCHAR(1)
  , Flag BIT
);

INSERT INTO @Test (ID, Category, Flag)
VALUES (1, 'A', 1)
  , (2, 'A', 0)
  , (3, 'A', 0)
  , (4, 'B', 0)
  , (5, 'C', 0);

SELECT T.ID
  , T.Category
  , T.Flag
FROM (
  SELECT ID
    , Category
    , Flag
    , MAX(CAST(Flag AS TINYINT)) OVER(PARTITION BY Category) AS MaxFlag
  FROM @Test
  ) AS T
WHERE T.MaxFlag = 1;
```

That's the output:

```
ID Category Flag  
-- -------- ----- 
1  A        True  
2  A        False 
3  A        False
```

This will find highest `Flag` for each category in your table, in your case it's probably true/false only and pick one who has `true(1)` only.

The conversion to `TINYINT` is needed because `MAX` doesn't accept a `BIT` argument.