# Select rows in Postgresql where condition is fullfiled by all the members

Tags: postgresql, exists

I have a question about a topic that was already discussed:

[select rows having condition met for group (without temporary table)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144214/select-rows-having-condition-met-for-group-without-temporary-table/323548?noredirect=1#comment631001_323548)

Let's say I have:

| ID | Name | Account | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | 0001 | 1928 |
| 2 | John | 0001 | 1908 |
| 3 | Mary | 0001 | 1918 |
| 4 | Paul | 0002 | 1899 |
| 5 | James | 0002 | 1913 |
| 6 | Laura | 0003 | 1925 |

By using EXISTS clause as shown in the link:

```
SELECT d.ID, d.Name d.Account, d.Year
FROM data a
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM data b WHERE Year < 1920 AND a.Account = b.Account
) ;
```

I obtain the Output:

| ID | Name | Account | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | 0001 | 1928 |
| 2 | John | 0001 | 1908 |
| 3 | Mary | 0001 | 1918 |
| 4 | Paul | 0002 | 1899 |
| 5 | James | 0002 | 1913 |

What query should i use in order to obtain:

| ID | Name | Account | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Paul | 0002 | 1899 |
| 5 | James | 0002 | 1913 |

If Year < 1920 at least for one line, no line from the "Account" field will not be selected.

Comment: What if you replace `EXISTS` with `NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: I modified my question in order to be easier to understand. If I use NOT EXISTS i obtain all the records where year > 1925

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, 1925 doesn't appear in your query so how could it behave that way?  Please show us a fiddle or something (https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than saying,

> Return this row if another row with the same `Account` exists that has `Year` less than 1920

you should be saying,

> Return this row if **no other** rows with the same `Account` exist that have `Year` of 1920 or above (**not less** than 1920),

thus putting `NOT` in two locations of your current condition:

```
NOT EXISTS ( ... NOT (Year < 1920) )
```

This is the entire query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  data AS this
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      data AS that
    WHERE
      that.Account = this.Account
      AND NOT (that.Year < 1920)
      -- or: AND that.Year >= 1920
  )
;
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for your reply, it works great for me.